# How can I solve this html CSS positioning issue

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to create header, left nav, content area, right nav and footer.
But my content area is streching and right nav is underneath content area. I want right nav to be underneath header. And only content area should stretch or narrowed while resizing window. Left nav and Right nav I want is fixed size.
How can I solve this issue?
I am new in css.
Thank you in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <style>
    body {
      min-height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .header {
      background-color: navy;
      color: white;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      height: 30px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .main {
      position: relative;
      top: 30px;
    }
    
    .content {
      position: relative;
      left: 230px;
    }
    
    .left-navbar {
      background: steelblue;
      position: fixed;
      top: 30px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 230px;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .content-area {
      position: relative;
      background: aqua;
    }
    
    .right-sidebar {
      position: fixed;
      background: lightblue;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 230px;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .footer {
      background: yellow;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='app'>
    <div class='header'>
      Header
    </div>
    <div class='main'>
      <div class='left-navbar'>
        Left Sidebar
      </div>
      <div class='content'>
        <div class="content-area">
          Content Area
        </div>
        <div class='right-sidebar'>
          Right Sidebar
        </div>
        <footer class='footer'>
          Footer
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I solved it like below. Can someone say me that it's standard solution or not? Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <style>
    body {
      min-width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }

    header {
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 35px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .left-nav {
      background-color: yellow;
      position: fixed;
      top: 35px;
      width: 230px;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .right-sidebar {
      background-color: aqua;
      position: fixed;
      top: 35px;
      right: 0;
      width: 230px;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    .content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 35px;
      left: 230px;
      right: 230px;
      width: auto;
    }

    .main {
      background-color: darkgreen;
    }

    footer {
      background-color: darkred;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  <nav class="left-nav">
    Left Navbar
  </nav>
  <div class="right-sidebar">
    Right Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position. The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position. The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems for me as a task for css-grid in combination with `position: sticky;`. instead of fixed positions.

Comment: @tacoshy Thanks for your suggestion. I just wanted to make left sidebar and right sidebar collapsable and expandable. I am not sure that with grid I can achieve that or not so I preferred like this from some guides on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move this block of code

```
<div class="right-sidebar"> 
</div>
```

in between the `left-navbar` class and the `content` class

*Like this*

```
<div class='main'>
            <div class='left-navbar'>
                Left Sidebar
            </div>

            <div class='right-sidebar'>
                Right Sidebar
            </div>
            
            <div class='content'>

                <div class="content-area">
                    Content Area
                </div>

                <footer class='footer'>
                    Footer
                </footer>

            </div>
            
        </div>
```

```css
body {
            min-height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: navy;
            color: white;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            height: 30px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .main {
            position: relative;
            top: 30px;
        }

        .content {
            position: relative;
            left: 230px;
        }

        .left-navbar {
            background: steelblue;
            position: fixed;
            top: 30px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 230px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .content-area {
            position: relative;
            background: aqua;
        }

        .right-sidebar {
            position: fixed;
            background: lightblue;
            right: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 230px;
            z-index: 3;
        }

        .footer {
            background: yellow;
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div class='header'>
            Header
        </div>

        <div class='main'>
            <div class='left-navbar'>
                Left Sidebar
            </div>

            <div class='right-sidebar'>
                Right Sidebar
            </div>
            
            <div class='content'>

                <div class="content-area">
                    Content Area
                </div>

                <footer class='footer'>
                    Footer
                </footer>

            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked and solved issue of right nav bar. But how can I solve content area and footer. Now it takes width more than available size and I need to scroll vertically to see content. I want it to be between left and right side bar.

Comment: @ManishkumarAdesara You can set a desired ```Max-width``` to ```.content``` class.